# How can I write an enum for date periods where not all periods have a static number of months?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, enum

I have an enum that works very well to represents date periods and the number of months in those date periods:

```
public enum StandardDatePeriod {

    ONE_MONTH(1),
    SIX_MONTH(6),
    ONE_YEAR(12),
    FIVE_YEAR(60),
    TEN_YEAR(120);

    private final long offsetInMonths;

    private StandardDatePeriod (long offsetInMonths) {
        this.offsetInMonths = offsetInMonths;
    }
    
    public LocalDate getStartDate(LocalDate endDate) {
        LocalDate startMonth = endDate.minusMonths(offsetInMonths-1);
        return startMonth.withDayOfMonth(1);
    }

}
```

But I have two other standard date periods that do not have a static number of months. One is `YEAR_TO_DATE` and another is `SINCE_CREATION`. Unlike `YEAR_TO_DATE` and other enum values, start date cannot be calculated for `SINCE_CREATION` (since it's number of months will vary per product). Nevertheless, it's considered a standard date period. How would I redesign this to account for these two other standard date periods?

**Update**

I use this enum in an object that has the average / total price of a product for each of the standard date periods:

```
@Data
public class StandardDatePrices {

   private Product product;

   private final EnumMap<StandardDatePeriod, BigDecimal> avergagePricePerStandardDatePeriod;

   private final EnumMap<StandardDatePeriod, BigDecimal> totalPricePerStandardDatePeriod;
```

I also use it to create the object:

```
EnumMap<StandardDatePeriod, BigDecimal> averagePrices = 
                new EnumMap<>(StandardDatePeriod.class);
        
        for (StandardDatePeriod period : StandardDatePeriod.values()) {
            
            LocalDate startDate = period.getStartDate(endDate);
            
            if (period == StandardDatePeriod.SINCE_CREATION) {
                startDate = productCreateDate;
            }
            
            BigDecimal averagePrice = pc.getAvergagePrice(startDate, endDate);
            avergagePrices.put(period, averagePrice);

        }
```

Comment: It doesn't really seem like an enum is the right tool for the job. You need a general purpose DatePeriod class to define arbitrary periods of time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581621/3092298

Comment: @Greg Burghardt - Thanks. I read the post and `Period` API. I'm considering how that might replace my current use of the `StandardDAtePeriod` enum. I updated my OP with how I currently use of the enum.

Comment: Dates are complicated.  Suggest using an existing package rather than roll your own.

Comment: Seriously error prone; you might be fixing date bugs for years (others have).  Use a pre-existing implementation for dates and time periods.

Comment: @Erik Eidt - Thanks. I do plan to leverage `LocalDate` methods but I'm not aware of some existing package (or how to use it) to accomplish my goals stated in the OP. Do you have an answer you could suggest?

Comment: @GregBurghardt - Seems like a lot agree with your idea of not using an enum. Would you mind giving your thoughts on how would use general purpose DatePeriod and show how the code in my OP update section would be changed to use it? I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: _"I use this enum in an object that has the average / total price of a product for each of the standard date periods"_ - now we are getting to the root of your problem. To be honest, it almost changes your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - That's completely fair. I'm sorry I didn't include that in my original post. If you have other thoughts on or beyond the already posted answers, I would greatly appreciate your input. I also understand if you'd rather not since I didn't have my original post well-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Java enum is a nice tool for the job, as you can override the methods in the concrete constants. The problem you face is, that you need a common signature.

Thus, when one concrete implementation needs a productCreateDate, you'll have to pass it into the methods for all implementations. As you extend your enum with more and more specific
constants, this may become quite unwieldy.

A common solution is, that you may create a parameter object, which contains all information passed.

But for now, I'd scratch the switch you posted, and instead modify the enum:

```
public enum StandardDatePeriod {
    ONE_MONTH(1),
    SIX_MONTH(6),
    ONE_YEAR(12),
    FIVE_YEAR(60),
    TEN_YEAR(120),
    SINCE_CREATION(0) {
        public LocalDate getStartDate(LocalDate endDate, LocalDate productCreateDate) {
            return productCreateDate;
        }
    };

    private final long offsetInMonths;

    private StandardDatePeriod (long offsetInMonths) {
        this.offsetInMonths = offsetInMonths;
    }
    
    public LocalDate getStartDate(LocalDate endDate, LocalDate productCreateDate) {
        LocalDate startMonth = endDate.minusMonths(offsetInMonths-1);
        return startMonth.withDayOfMonth(1);
    }
}
```

This way, you limit your changes to a single point in code (as long as the parameters are unchanged.)

Comment: and YEAR_TO_DATE in this design?

Comment: I did not see the code you use right now for YEAR_TO_DATE in the question. But simply continue on the same path: add the parameters you need to the common method signature and provide a specific implementation in the enum constant.

Answer (score 2):

### Go on with enums?

You could keep using your `enum` and use some tricks and magic numbers for special cases.  0 for `SINCE_CREATION` was already suggested. Why not 9999 for `YEAR_TO_DATE` and so on.

But this design **[is not open for extension nor closed to modification](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)**:

- First, you'll have to add some `if..else` and `switch` to deal with all the special situations and the magic numbers, unless you manage to use Java's syntactic sugar for enum with method override as [mtj](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/429508/209774) elegantly suggested,
- Then, every time someone will come with a new idea of a reference period, you’ll have to change your `enum` again, add even more overrides/branches, and retest all the code that uses it. This is neither flexible, nor does it promote reuse of periods across different applications.

### Increase flexibility with classes?

Alternatively, you could use an abstract class `StandardDatePeriod` with abstract methods such as `getStartDate(Date d)`, `getEndDate(Date d)`, `getDurationMonth()`, etc.  Specialized classes such as `FixedDurationPeriod` or `YearToDate` would extend the abstract class using the constructor to set any specific parameter (e.g number of months for `FixedDurationPeriod`).

A `PeriodRegisty` would hold instances of standard periods that need to be used in your value maps, and the maps could easily be generated, iterating on/mapping the registry.

It’s slightly more complex that the enum, but significantly more flexible: not only can you promote reuse of standard periods across applications, but you can also enrich or fine-tune reference periods at run-time (e.g.  using some configuration file to generate a personalized set).

Comment: I concur, that using magic numbers is not a good idea (and it is not the gist of my answer.) In a java enum, the enum class is a base class, while each declared constant is a derived class from this base, and has the ability to specialize and override methods, which is exactly what you suggest, only using the syntactic sugar the language offers. I 100% aggree, that using enums to switch over them (let alone in different places) is a bad idea and violation of the open-closed principle, but using the constants as specializations is a nice little strategy pattern.

Comment: @Christophe - Thanks. This is very helpful. Would your `StandardDatePeriod` extend `java.time.Period`? On another note: after more thought, I'm considering if I should have a separate class to represent 'DateRange` ala [Fowler's DateRange](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Range.html). It seems that might be best for returning a `Period` from two dates or getting a start date from an end date and `Period`. Then, if I use `DateRange` and `java.time.Period`, I wonder about the usefulness of custom Period classes such `StandardDatePeriod`. The `PeriodRegistry` & likely a `PeriodRegister` seem great

Comment: @mtj Thank you for your remark. Indeed, the overriding of methods for individual enum members can avoid overuse of if/else and limit the negative aspects of magic numbers. I‘n slightly edit to avoid any misrepresentation of your answer in this regard. However, the syntactic sugar does not change my remark about OCP, because [enum cannot be extended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414755/3723423). Every time a new standard period is invented, you need to change the enum and propagate this change. And it’s not just about compile time, but also about runtime flexibiliy

Comment: @James Indeed, a date range could be an alternative. It is able to deal with all the situations, including SINCE_BEGINNING (no start date).  However,  the range is fixed.  This appears different from your semantic, where I understand it's not FIVE as five yers back from "now", and  "now" has a tendency to change. I didn't ask, by the way, but it was not clear for your value map how you'd update them (but maybe they are not persisted and my question is irrelevant).  And the semantic of "5 years back from now" and "since the beginning which is by coincidence 5 years"  is different.

Comment: @James You may also consider to combine both ideas:  have a range policy (FIVE,  SINCE_BEGINNING),  that generates a date range for any "now" you propose.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks for your insights. You're understanding is correct: it is FIVE years back from a variable end date as supplied by a user. My comment was about the idea of separating the concept of period and date ranges into separate classes. That is, use a `DateRange` class to determine the start date for a given end date and period of time. Use the `java.time.Period` to represent the period of times. For example, `fiveYears = java.time.Period.ofMonths(60)`. Then get the start date via `new DateRange(endDate, fiveYears).getStartDate()`

Comment: @Christophe I've been thinking more about your answer. I agree about the increased flexibility with classes and avoiding the downsides you noted of using an enum. However, with classes, I lose the enum map which is very convenient when I need to get an average price for a certain period (e.g. mapping to DTO with fields for each of the periods). The enum couples a label with the period and gives me a nice way to get at a date range (i.e. start date for a given end date). I think (at least in my use) classes might be a fair bit more trouble to use.  Perhaps, I'm missing something though.

Comment: @James There is no perfect design, we just have to maximise the pros and minimize the cons in our own situation. If you develop standard software packages,  the class has the advantage of higher flexibility and configurability.  But as said in my answer,  this comes at the cost of a higher complexity.  SInce you'd have a generator, you could generate some maps, and you could use a description instead of an enum.  You could even localise it in several languages.  But you'd have to write some extra code.  If all this added flexibility does not give you significant benefit, stick to the enum ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need a method to convert the enum into it’s currently correct meaning. I’d recommend NOT to use “correct” values for 6, 12 etc. Months so that nobody assumes this will always work. You don’t want code written that works for the first five enum values (and fails horribly for the other two).

Comment: Can you give more details on converting "the enum into its correct meaning"? What values would use in lieu of 6, 12, etc.? Perhaps, `java.time.Period` instead of long for the `offsetInMonths` field.

Answer (score 0):

Would the `StandardDatePeriod` be used in other contexts? Because if it is only used in contexts where `Product` is known, I would see it fitting to move the logic from where you determine the start date into the `StandardDatePeriod` objects themselves, as having this logic outside seems to be a form of abstraction leaking from the Period concept you have in place.

For example, you could replace `getStartDate(LocalDate endDate)` with `getStartDate(Product product)` (or `getStartDate(LocalDate endDate, Product product)` if the `endDate` is not part of the product), so that the implementation of the `StandardDatePeriod` can directly compute the start date in whichever way it needs to, considering the creation date if required, or any other data from the product.

This would mean that at least the `YEAR_TO_DATE` and `SINCE_CREATION` enum constants would need to be anonymous sublcasses of the current `StandardDatePeriod`, to override the `getStartDate` method and implement in a different way than the month-based ones. Or, you could also have different enums that implement the same interface so you can use them the same way (except, maybe you need to replace `EnumMap` by something else too).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think `YEAR_TO_DATE` and `SINCE_CREATION` already are subclasses of the `StandardDatePeriod`.  This something mtj noted and as you said it would solve the different ways start date is calculated. Please let me know if you were thinking of something different though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your trying to represent dynamic periods (`YEAR_TO_DATE` and `SINCE_CREATION`) in an enum,  `StandardDatePeriod`. Although both are periods, the period of time they cover are unknown at compile time. So, in that sense, the enum is not the right tool. However, the other periods (e.g. `ONE_MONTH`) are fixed and known at compile time. So, they work as a enum.

But you're not really interested in the period of time anyway. For example, you don't care about the period of time (e.g. 2 months, 4 months, etc.) that `YEAR_TO_DATE` covers. Your code never calculates this period of time b/c it doesn't need it. Instead, all you actually want is the date range covered by `YEAR_TO_DATE` (e.g. Jan 1, 2021 - Feb 28, 2021).

I see two options already discussed by others:

1. Keep with the enum as suggested by [mtj](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/271466/mtj). Know that it will have problems such as having method parameter(s) that aren't used and other issues as noted by [Christophe](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/209774/christophe). You can change the semantics a bit by letting the constructor take a `java.time.Period` and call it fixed period. Then, non-fixed periods (e.g. YEAR_TO_DATE) would pass null. The advantage here is simplicity.
2. Redesign similar to how [Christophe](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/209774/christophe) suggested. Create a class to represent date range (could do for 1 as well).